# "Cannot modify managed RLMArray outside of a write transaction." in XCTest

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm attempting to write some unit tests for my view models that interact with Realm.  The logic works fine when run on device / simulator, but triggers a ""RLMException", "Cannot modify managed RLMArray outside of a write transaction" when unit tested.

My test case is as follows...

```
func testThatNewlyAddedPaymentsAreReturned() throws {
    let payment = Payment(recipient: "Matt", amount: Decimal(1.0), date: Date(), note: "")
    try model.addPayment(payment: payment) // Throws exception
    XCTAssertTrue(model.payments?.contains(payment) ?? false)
}
```

In the test case above, the `model` variable is the view model class, which has a simple one line implementation...

```
func addPayment(payment: Payment) throws {
    try self.budget?.addPayment(payment: payment)
}
```

This in turn calls through to the `Budget` class where the Realm interactions take place.

```
func addPayment(payment: Payment) throws {
    let realm = try Realm()
    try realm.write {
        _payments.append(payment)
    }
}
```

Note that contrary to the exception message the `private var _payments = List<Payment>()` property is being modified within a Realm write transaction.

I've configured the default Realm configuration in the unit test as follows...

```
override func setUp() {
    var config = Realm.Configuration.init()
    // Set this as the configuration used for the default Realm
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
    config.inMemoryIdentifier = "BudgetTests"
    try! repository = BudgetRepository.init(realm: Realm(configuration: config))
    try! initialiseViewModel()
}
```

Comment: While you have indicated which line throws, can you add a breakpoint within that call here `func addPayment(payment` and step through your code to determine which line actually isn't working?  There's several nested throws with no error handling so it's not clear what is actually throwing. Adding Do-Catch blocks would probably help narrow down the issue as well.

Comment: The exact line is `_payments.append(payment)` e.g. the addition of the new item to the managed object array in the Realm object within the write block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the test setup to initialise the realm using the no-args initializer fixed the issue e.g.

Replacing...

`try! repository = BudgetRepository.init(realm: Realm(configuration: config))`

... with ...

`try! repository = BudgetRepository.init(realm: Realm())`

Oddly this would appear to imply that opening a Realm with the default configratuion e.g. `Realm()` does not produce the equivalent Realm as initializating one and manually supplying the default configuration.